# Control Panel > Region Tab Won't Open

Tags: windows-8.1

I recently bought a MSI laptop with Windows 8.1. When I go into the "Control Panel" and click on the "Region" or "Change date, time or number formats" tab nothing happens at all. This doesn't happen with any other tab in the control panel.

I found similar issue in here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/windows-81-control-panel-region-tab-wont-open/bd3af81f-7693-4e0d-886f-f7b26f108ede
but answers there did not fix the issue.
I can't find a solution anywhere. Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure you are operating Administrator privileges.

If you're running administrative and still have issues try the following.

It might be a policy setting that is disabling Region and Date settings. This can be changed in Windows 8 Pro and Enterprise editions with the Local Security Policy Editor; see http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/113557-date-time-allow-prevent-users-groups-changing.html for more information on that. There is also a Registry key, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Control Panel\International\, that might have been changed; see http://www.kapilarya.com/use-specific-geographic-location.

Another possibility is missing Windows System files; use **sfc /scannow** in a CMD prompt to scan for missing or bad files and fix the issues. Review the *long* log afterwards, searching for errors. See https://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833/en-us.

Comment: no one of them didn't help. after using `sfc /scannow` in a CMD showed everything are fine and hasn't any cropped or lost files.